# how to calculate smooth normals for 10,000,000 vertices?

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming, normals

I am trying to calculate smooth normals with angle weight for a huge mesh with 10 million vertices. Currently, i am using map/dictionary to store the traingles connected to a vertex. That is, for each vertex,  **I loop through the entire mesh to find triangles connected to a single vertex** and store them in a map for that vertex. I am doing this for 10 million triangles. So, i iterate 10 million x 10 million times to calculate normals for the whole mesh. It takes around 8 seconds to create the map itself. I also have to animate this mesh dynamically calculating the normals for 10 instances. Is there a possibility to move these computations to shaders?

Comment: It seems like you should not need any nesting to generate such a map. What does your code look like for generating the map(s)?

Comment: Re-generating the mesh and normals every time you animate it does not sound practical. How is this mesh generated? Is there some possibility you could compute normals implicitly as part of the generation process, or transform existing normals rather than generate them from scratch? Or possibly move the generation into the GPU, so you're only animating a lower-resolution control mesh?

Comment: In addition to the expense of recalculating so often, most graphics situations use array & index based data structures for performance reasons. Is there a reason you're using a dictionary/map instead? Also, are the connection between vertices ever changing? If not, then you only need to calculate the vertex neighbors once.

Comment: @DMGregory I have displacement information of vertices for each instance of the animation and the base mesh.As you proposed, I can precompute the normals for all instances during base mesh generation. But in my case, the user will pause the animation and apply deformation to vertices. So, if one instance changes, then I have to calculate remaining instances normals. Do you have any ideas

Comment: Why do you need so many vertices?

Comment: @Balint The model I am working is a cae mesh of an engine. Each vertex will have deformation info. So, somehow I have to handle them

Comment: Can you show us what you're trying to accomplish? It sounds like there may be much simpler ways to achieve what you want, but we don't have a clear picture of the end goal or player-facing experience here.

Comment: @DMGregory  Currently I am developing a CAE post processor. The application uses opengl for rendering. The cae model contains information on vertices, displacement of vertices and uvs. Now I have an engine model with 10 million vertices, displacement, uvs etc. for a single instance, meaning the initial undeformed model. Then, I also have 10 different deformation information for the vertices, so that I can apply these deformation to the undeformed model to create 10 different deformed models during every frame of the animation. The user will pause the animation apply a different scale.

Comment: @DMGregory So, again I calculate the deformation, normals for all instance

Comment: @Pikalek I will change map to array. I think this will improve performance but still I have to generate the normals at runtime in CPU right. I am wondering if there is a way to utilize GPU for these calculations or there is a better way to calculate normals.